# How to include custom ClassLoader coverage in EclEmma reports?

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader, jacoco, eclemma

I have a number of classes that statically initialize constants based on system arch properties. To fully test them, I have used a custom class loader to reload the classes from files after changing properties. However EclEmma reports miss the coverage of classes loaded this way.

I am able to manually show coverage by adding Jacoco instrumentation in the class loader:

```java
public class TestFlags {
    public static final int O_RDONLY = 0x0;
    public static final int O_WRONLY = 0x1;
    public static final int O_CREAT;
    public static final int O_TRUNC;
    
    public TestFlags() {}
    
    static {
        if (CoverageTest.isMac) {
            O_CREAT = 0x200;
            O_TRUNC = 0x400;
        } else {
            O_CREAT = 0x40;
            O_TRUNC = 0x200;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.jacoco.core.analysis.*;
import org.jacoco.core.data.*;
import org.jacoco.core.instr.Instrumenter;
import org.jacoco.core.runtime.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public final class CoverageTest {
    public static boolean isMac;

    @Test
    public void testFlagCoverage() throws Exception {
        try (Coverage cov = new Coverage(TestFlags.class)) {
            isMac = true;
            cov.instantiate(TestFlags.class);
            isMac = false;
            cov.instantiate(TestFlags.class);
            cov.showCoverage(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Captures coverage for specified classes only.
     */
    public static class Coverage implements AutoCloseable {
        private static final Map<Integer, String> lineStatusMap = Map.of(ICounter.NOT_COVERED, "-",
            ICounter.PARTLY_COVERED, ".", ICounter.FULLY_COVERED, "+");
        private final IRuntime runtime = new LoggerRuntime();
        private final Instrumenter instrumenter = new Instrumenter(runtime);
        private final RuntimeData data = new RuntimeData();
        private final Set<String> coverageClassNames;

        public Coverage(Class<?>... coverageClasses) {
            try {
                coverageClassNames = Stream.of(coverageClasses).map(Class::getName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
                runtime.startup(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            runtime.shutdown();
        }

        /**
         * Use a new instrumenting class loader to instantiate the class.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public <T> T instantiate(Class<T> cls) throws Exception {
            return (T) new InstrumentingClassLoader().loadClass(cls.getName()).getConstructor()
                .newInstance();
        }

        public void showCoverage(boolean lines) throws IOException {
            var exec = new ExecutionDataStore();
            data.collect(exec, new SessionInfoStore(), false);
            var cov = new CoverageBuilder();
            var analyzer = new Analyzer(exec, cov);
            for (var name : coverageClassNames)
                analyzer.analyzeClass(loadClassFile(name), name);
            for (var cc : cov.getClasses()) {
                var counter = cc.getInstructionCounter();
                System.out.printf("%s: %d/%d %d%%\n", cc.getName(), counter.getCoveredCount(),
                    counter.getTotalCount(), Math.round(counter.getCoveredRatio() * 100));
                if (lines) for (int i = cc.getFirstLine(); i <= cc.getLastLine(); i++)
                    System.out.printf("Line %2s: %s%n", i,
                        lineStatusMap.getOrDefault(cc.getLine(i).getStatus(), ""));
            }
        }

        private static byte[] loadClassFile(String className) throws IOException {
            var fileName = className.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
            try (var in = CoverageTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
                return in.readAllBytes();
            }
        }

        private class InstrumentingClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
            @Override
            public Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                try {
                    var bytes = instrumenter.instrument(loadClassFile(name), name);
                    return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new ClassNotFoundException(name, e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                if (!coverageClassNames.contains(name)) return super.loadClass(name);
                var cls = findLoadedClass(name);
                return cls != null ? cls : findClass(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With EclEmma, launch VM args show `-javaagent:.../jacocoagent.jar=...,output=tcpclient,port=NNNNN`. I tried sending the data with a socket and `RemoteControlWriter`, but it didn't show on the report, perhaps because the session ids don't match.

Is there a way for EclEmma to pick up coverage from custom ClassLoaders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around in debug mode, it turns out the agent `CoverageTransformer.transform()` does get called, but returns *null* since *inclNoLocationClasses* is not set, and `defineClass()` doesn't pass in a `ProtectionDomain`.

If I pass in `TestFlags.class.getProtectionDomain()`, the coverage does show up.